# How to head DataFrame with Map[String,Long] column and preserve types?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame on which I have applied `filter` condition

```
val colNames = customerCountDF
  .filter($"fiscal_year" === maxYear && $"fiscal_month" === maxMnth)
```

out of all the selected rows, I just want the last column of one row.

The last column type is `Map[String, Long]`. I want all the keys of the map as `List[String]`.

I tried below syntax

```
val colNames = customerCountDF
  .filter($"fiscal_year" === maxYear && $"fiscal_month" === maxMnth)
  .head
  .getMap(14)
  .keySet
  .toList
  .map(_.toString)
```

I am using `map(_.toString)` to convert a `List[Nothing]` to `List[String]`. The error that I am getting is:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toString)
[error]        val colNames = customerCountDF.filter($"fiscal_year" === maxYear && $"fiscal_month" === maxMnth).head().getMap(14).keySet.toList.map(_.toString)
```

The `df` is as follows:

```
+-------------+-----+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
|division_name|  low| call_type|fiscal_year|fiscal_month|  region_name|abandon_rate_percent|answered_calls|connects|equiv_week_calls|equiv_weeks|equivalent_calls|num_customers|offered_calls|                  pv|
+-------------+-----+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
|     NATIONAL|PHONE|CABLE CARD|       2016|           1|ALL DIVISIONS|                0.02|         10626|       0|             0.0|        0.0|         10649.8|            0|        10864|Map(subscribers_c...|
|     NATIONAL|PHONE|CABLE CARD|       2016|           1|      CENTRAL|                0.02|          3591|       0|             0.0|        0.0|          3598.6|            0|         3667|Map(subscribers_c...|
+-------------+-----+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+--------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

one row of just last column selected is

```
[Map(subscribers_connects -> 5521287, disconnects_hsd -> 7992, subscribers_xfinity home -> 6277491, subscribers_bulk units -> 4978892, connects_cdv -> 41464, connects_disconnects -> 16945, connects_hsd -> 32908, disconnects_internet essentials -> 10319, disconnects_disconnects -> 3506, disconnects_video -> 8960, connects_xfinity home -> 43012)]
```

I'd like to get the keys of the last column as `List[String]` after applying the filter condition and taking just one row from the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type problem is easy to solve, by explicitly specifying the type parameters at the source which is `getMap(14)`. Since you know that the you are expecting a `Map` of `String -> Int` key-value pairs, just replace `getMap(14)` by `getMap[String, Int](14)`.

And as far as the `getMap[String, Int](14)` being an empty `Map`, that has to do with your data and you simply have an empty map at `index 14` in the `head` row.

### More Details

In Scala when you create a `List[A]`, Scala infers the type by using the information available.

For example,

```
// Explicitly provide the type parameter info
scala> val l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
// l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

// Infer the type parameter by using the arguments passed to List constructor,
scala> val l2 = List(1, 2)
// l2: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

So, what happens when you create an empty list,

```
// Explicitly provide the type parameter info
scala> val l1: List[Int] = List()
// l1: List[Int] = List()

    // Infer the type parameter by using the arguments passed to List constructor,
// but surprise, there are no argument since you are creating empty list
scala> val l2 = List()
// l2: List[Nothing] = List()
```

So, now when Scala does not know anything, it will choose the most suitable type it can find which is the "empty" type `Nothing`.

The same thing happens when you do a `toList` on other collection objects, it tries to infer the type parameter from the source object.

```
scala> val ks1 = Map.empty[Int, Int].keySet
// ks1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set()
scala> val l1 = ks1.toList
// l1: List[Int] = List()

scala> val ks2 = Map.empty.keySet
// ks: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing] = Set()
scala> val l2 = ks2.toList
// l1: List[Nothing] = List()
```

Similarly, the `getMap(14)` which you called on the `head` `Row` of the `DataFrame`, infers the type parameters for the `Map` using the values it is getting from the `Row` at `index` `14`. So, if it does not get anything at the said index the returned map will be same as `Map.empty` which is a `Map[Nothing, Nothing]`.

Which means that your whole,

```
val colNames = customerCountDF.filter($"fiscal_year" === maxYear && $"fiscal_month" === maxMnth).head.getMap(14).keySet.toList.map(_.toString)
```

is equivalent to,

```
val colNames = Map.empty.keySet.toList.map(_.toString)
```

And hence,

```
scala> val l = List()
// l1: List[Nothing] = List()

val colNames = l.map(_.toString)
```

To summarise the above, any `List[Nothing]` can only be an empty list.

Now, there are two problems, one is about the type-problem in `List[Nothing]` the other is about it being empty.

Answer (score 1):

After `filter` you can just select the column and get as Map as below

```
first().getAs[Map[String, Long]]("pv").keySet
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're accessing a single column only (at the 14th position), why not making your developer's live a bit easier (and help the people who would support your code later)?

Try the following:

```
val colNames = customerCountDF
  .where($"fiscal_year" === maxYear)  // Split one long filter into two
  .where($"fiscal_month" === maxMnth) // where is a SQL-like alias of filter
  .select("pv")                       // Take just the field you need to work with
  .as[Map[String, Long]]              // Map it to the proper type
  .head                               // Load just the single field (all others are left aside)
  .keySet                             // That's just a pure Scala
```

I think the above code says what it does in such a clear way (and I think should be the fastest out of the provided solutions since it just loads a single `pv` field to a JVM object on the driver).

Answer (score -1):

A workaround to get the final result in List[String]. Check this out:

```
scala> val customerCountDF=Seq((2018,12,Map("subscribers_connects" -> 5521287L, "disconnects_hsd" -> 7992L, "subscribers_xfinity home" -> 6277491L, "subscribers_bulk units" -> 4978892L, "connects_cdv" -> 41464L, "connects_disconnects" -> 16945L, "connects_hsd" -> 32908L, "disconnects_internet essentials" -> 10319L, "disconnects_disconnects" -> 3506L, "disconnects_video" -> 8960L, "connects_xfinity home" -> 43012L))).toDF("fiscal_year","fiscal_month","mapc")
customerCountDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [fiscal_year: int, fiscal_month: int ... 1 more field]

scala> val maxYear =2018
maxYear: Int = 2018

scala> val maxMnth = 12
maxMnth: Int = 12

scala> val colNames = customerCountDF.filter($"fiscal_year" === maxYear && $"fiscal_month" === maxMnth).first.getMap(2).keySet.mkString(",").split(",").toList
colNames: List[String] = List(subscribers_connects, disconnects_hsd, subscribers_xfinity home, subscribers_bulk units, connects_cdv, connects_disconnects, connects_hsd, disconnects_internet essentials, disconnects_disconnects, disconnects_video, connects_xfinity home)

scala>
```